# How to call Paypal rest API to the get access token through rest in java

Tags: java, paypal

I am testing this with postmaster tool but no results. coming from the PayPal and url is https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token. can any one give solution. For me getting this error : {
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Invalid client credentials"
}

Comment: did you get access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure your client and secret are getting passed in the Authorization header, essentially as user/password in basic auth.

This page details the process pretty well.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/